# how to print the elements with text value that contains in a list selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Anyone know how to print out all the elements that contain in a list with text value in selenium c#? Try to do like the code below it print out blank value. But if i were to put writeline with elem only the value was display but it is not in text form. I would like to get value with text.

**Code:**

```
IList<IWebElement> attachmentList = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("comment-box"));

foreach (IWebElement element in attachmentList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Text);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="comment-box">
        <!-- Comment Image -->
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div id="attachmentImgSFHD-24" class="attachmentImg">
                <img src="downloadAttachment?attachmenturl=/secure/thumbnail/10111/_thumb_10111.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Attachment details -->
        <div  class="col-xs-10">
            <div class="commentContent">
                <div class="topRow">
                    <div class="username">ApplicationLink.png</div>
                    <div class="commentTimeStamp">31400 KB</div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottomRow">
                    <div class="commentDisplay">
                        <a href="downloadAttachment?filename=ApplicationLink.png&id=10111&mimeType=image/png&showAttachment=true" target="_blank">Download</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment-box">
        <!-- Comment Image -->
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div id="attachmentImgSFHD-24" class="attachmentImg">
                <img src="downloadAttachment?attachmenturl=/secure/thumbnail/10313/_thumb_10313.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Attachment details -->
        <div  class="col-xs-10">
            <div class="commentContent">
                <div class="topRow">
                    <div class="username">test.jpg</div>
                    <div class="commentTimeStamp">7423 KB</div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottomRow">
                    <div class="commentDisplay">
                        <a href="downloadAttachment?filename=test.jpg&id=10313&mimeType=image/jpeg&showAttachment=true" target="_blank">Download</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<br/>
```

Comment: Post the relevant html.

Comment: haven't you already asked this today?

Comment: @vasily.sib i update it with more detail

Comment: @Guy posted the html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IList<IWebElement> attachmentList = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("comment-box"));

foreach (IWebElement element in attachmentList)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.WriteLine(element.Text);
}
```

it works fine by putting the thread.sleep code

Answer (score 0):

The elements don't have text in the html, so `element.Text` is empty. Use

```
Console.WriteLine(element.GetAttribute("value"));
```

Comment: i wanna get the ApplicationLink.png word from this div
<div class="username">ApplicationLink.png</div>

Comment: @Kevin You should have posted it in your question. Use `driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("username"));`

Comment: i tried using that. but can't get the text value that is why i wanna see what are the element with text that contains in the attachmentList

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below Xpath to get the attachment details

**Xpath:** `//div[@class='comment-box']//div[@class='commentContent']//div[@class='username']`

**Code:**

```
IList<IWebElement> attachmentList = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='comment-box']//div[@class='commentContent']//div[@class='username']"));

foreach (IWebElement element in attachmentList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Text);//It will print all the attachment name like 'ApplicationLink.png,test.jpg'
}
```

Comment: @Kevin: Whether the comment-box resides in any iframe?

Comment: it does not consist of iframe. that is why i wanted to see what is the text value in the elements displaying in the list first so that i can know where went wrong

Comment: Please check whether any element is getting highlighted in application, when the xpath ( //div[@class='comment-box']//div[@class='commentContent']//div[@class='username']) is typed in Developer Tools. Press F12 and search with (//div[@class='comment-box']//div[@class='commentContent']//div[@class='username'])

Comment: @Kevin: Please check the output by adding the Console.WriteLine(attachmentList.Count); statement above the for loop.

Comment: the count displayed as 6

Comment: try to search //div[@class='comment-box']//div[@class='commentContent']//div[@class='username'] nothing appear in the search box

Comment: Whether the URL can be shared? or is it a private URL?

Comment: the URL is private URL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177933/discussion-between-kevin-and-subburaj).